# Como verificar se existe somente uma posição no elemento do array?

Tags: php, javascript

Em meu código eu faço uma pesquisa no `BD` adicionando ao `array` os resultados encontrados. E antes do valor eu insiro uma letra para identificar os resultados.

```
<?php
    $w_select ="SELECT *    FROM public.sai_cad_patr_seri WHERE 
                                            sai_cad_patr_seri.fk_seq_cara_peri = '$arr_w_param[17]'";
    $w_querybusc = "$w_select;"; 
    $w_queryresult=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusc);
    $index = 0;
    $patr = array();
    $seri = array();        
    while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresult))
    {
        $patr[$index] = "P".trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr);
        $seri[$index] = "S".trim($w_registro->tx_num_seri);
        $index++;
    }
?>
```

Mas eu me deparei com o seguinte problema ... Depois de ter pego esses valores eu adiciono eles em um `array JS`, mas caso o `array $patr` só tenha inserido a letra **'P'** ou vise-versa com o `$seri` e nenhum valor em seguida ele vai ocupar espaço e ira atrapalhar qualquer alteração seguinte.

Assim gostaria de saber se tem como verificar se tem alguma posição vazia depois do **'P'** ou **'S'**!

```
$patr = [P ];
```

Comment: Não seria melhor criar um campo (elemento em uma nova dimensão do *array*) e tratar o tipo separadamente do conteúdo do cadastro? Essas solução de fazer uma linguição de *string* para juntar dados e depois ter que tratá-los excepcionalmente não é uma prática muito recomendada.

Comment: Sim concordo com você @bigown, mas referente ao meu supervisor eu devo fazer essa tripa por "boas práticas da empresa"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PHP

De forma a verificares se a segunda posição é um espaço, podes fazer uso da função [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) ou da função [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) para recolher os dois primeiros caracteres consoante os dados sejam [single-byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-byte_encoding) ou [multi-byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-byte_character_set):

```php
// singlebyte
$resultado = substr($valor, 0, 2);

// multibyte
$resultado = mb_substr($valor, 0, 2);
```

Depois realizas uma comparação entre o que foi recolhido e esse mesmo valor filtrado pela função [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```php
if ($resultado != trim($resultado)) {
  // tinha um espaço
} else {
  // não tinha um espaço
}
```

Se pretendes saber especificamente se o espaço estava à direita, ou seja, após a letra `P`, podes fazer uso da função [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

A solução pode ser compactada numa função:

```
function comEspaco($valor='', $posicao=2) {

    $resultado = mb_substr($valor, 0, $posicao);

    return ($resultado != rtrim($resultado));
}

echo comEspaco('P '); // TRUE
echo comEspaco('P');  // FALSE
```

Este exemplo pode ser visto no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/V902yE).

---

## JavaScript

Em Javascript podes fazer a verificação com recurso ao método [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) que te permite obter o caractere na posição X e posteriormente com recurso ao método [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) para limpar qualquer espaço e assim realizar a comparação:

```js
var valor     = 'P ',
    resultado = valor.charAt(1);

alert( resultado != resultado.trim() ); // TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer uma verificação usando a função `substr`.

A função vai retornar a parte determinada de uma string qualquer.

No caso seria algo parecido com o código abaixo:

```
if (substr($part["P "], 1, 1) === " "){
    // do stuff when true
} else {
    // do stuff when false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Realize um count no php

```
$count = count($patr);
```

Se a contagem for 1, entao significa que o array só tem uma posição.

Referências
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count.asp
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não faz algo do tipo:

```
while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresult))
{
    $w_patr = trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr);
    $w_seri = trim($w_registro->tx_num_seri);

    if (!empty($w_patr))
        $patr[$index] = 'P' . $w_patr;

    if (!empty($w_seri))
        $seri[$index] = 'S' . $w_seri;

    $index++;
}
```